# Как вызвать функцию, которая вложена в другую функцию?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая структура кода на JavaScript:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  initSky() {
    function imitate() {

    }

    function tracker() {

    }
  }
</script>
<script>
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    for (j; j <= finDay; j++) {
      imitate();
    };
  });
</script>
```

как вызвать функцию imitate() не меняя её местоположения?

Comment: никак, кроме того, у тебя синтаксическая ошибка при объявлении функции _initSky_ - приведенный код вообще не работает

Comment: у меня всё работает, я просто убрал лишнее, и привел структуру кода, чтобы было понятно откуда функция вызывается. весь код заливать не видел смысла.

Comment: Я перенес твой код в сниппет, и ты можешь убедиться, что в нем синтаксическая ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разве что сделать функции через глобальные переменные:

```html
<script>
  function initSky() {
    imitate = function() { // пробрасываем функции в глобальную область видимости

    }

    tracker = function() {

    }
  }
  initSky();
</script>
<script>
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    for (j; j <= finDay; j++) {
      imitate();
    };
  });
</script>
```